# Annotate objects in a queryset with next and previous object ids

Tags: django, postgresql, orm

How do I annotate the objects in a Django ORM queryset so that every items contain IDs of the the object before (previous) and the one after (next)? I am using PostgreSQL and Django 1.11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [window functions `lag()` and `lead()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html):

```
SELECT *
     , lag(id)  OVER (ORDER BY id) AS prev_id  -- same order as query
     , lead(id) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS next_id  -- same order as query
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY id;
```

Comment: Thank you. If I figure out how to do this successfully with Django I can accept this as the answer. Queryset.annotate(next=RawSQL(select lag(id) OVER (ORDER BY id), [])) just seems to return None

Comment: @jmn this worked for me: qs = qs.annotate(next=RawSQL("lead(id)  OVER (ORDER BY id)", []))

Comment: @devxplorer If I drop the select, and write the query like that I get ProgrammingError "window functions are not allowed in GROUP BY"

Comment: @jmn show us what query do you have and what you want to get, otherwise we can hardly help you

Comment: I found out that because I'm using pagination I get an error in the COUNT query that is performed. Using your query worked in shell.

Answer (score 0):

I think a slightly more detailed example in Django scope might help someone. Check out the official documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_previous_by_FOO)

I use it in a view and simply update the response object:

```
response_data = {}
user = request.user

# put any data in this dict according to the
# logic you have in your view

response_data.update({
    "previous_object":
        get_next_or_previous_object(user, serializer.data, next_obj=False),
    "next_object":
        get_next_or_previous_object(user, serializer.data, next_obj=True),
})



def get_next_or_previous_object(user, data, next_obj=None):
    """
    Get the previous or next object from the given data list.

    If it is not possible to get the object returns None
    :param data: List of objects from which the previous or next object
                 will be taken. OrderedDict and not queryset.
    :param bool next_obj: whether the next object should be returned or
                          the previous one. True = next, False = previous
    :return: the previous/next object or None
    """

    # Get datetime field name which will be used for obtaining the
    # next/previous object
    datetime_field_name = MyView.datetime_field_name
    object_index = 0 if next_obj else -1

    # Get the original object by its id
    try:
        object_id = data[object_index]["id"]
    except (IndexError, KeyError):
        object_id = None

    try:
        parent_object = MyModel.objects.get(id=object_id)
        if next_obj:
            # Example of the method name: get_next_by_my_timestamp_field
            next_method = getattr(
                MyModel, f"get_next_by_{datetime_field_name}")
            object_to_get = next_method(
                parent_object, user=user)
        else:
            # Example of the method name: get_previous_by_my_timestamp_field
            previous_method = getattr(
                MyModel, f"get_previous_by_{datetime_field_name}")
            object_to_get = previous_method(
                parent_object, user=user)

        serializer = MyView.serializer_class(object_to_get)
        previous_next_object = serializer.data
    except MyModel.DoesNotExist:
        previous_next_object = None

    return previous_next_object
```