# Difference with previous object in django queryset annotation

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Let's assume that I have following model:

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    some_integer = models.IntegerField()
```

and I have 3 instances of this model:

```
TestModel.objects.create(some_integer=100)
TestModel.objects.create(some_integer=50)
TestModel.objects.create(some_integer=20)
```

and I'd like to annotate queryset somehow to be able to get following results:

```
for obj in TestModel.objects.annotate(difference=...):
    print(obj.difference)
=> 50  # 100 - 50
=> 30  # 50 - 30
=> None  # we don't have anything created after this record
```

Any chance of doing this with Django(2.0) querysets or should I do this 'manually' in Python? We can safely assume that objects are ordered by pk or some date so ordering is preserved.

Comment: I think the *conceptual* problem is that a standard relational database has no notion of previous or next. The elements can be returned in *any* order, unless the elements are explicitly ordered.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem we can assume that QuerySet is ordered by pk or some date, I've updated description with this information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47256432/10310124), if you want to do it with raw SQL, you could do it this way:

```
SELECT *,
       LEAD("some_integer") OVER(ORDER BY "id") AS "next_val",
       "some_integer" - "next_val" AS "difference"
FROM "myapp_testmodel";
```

However, from Django version `2.0` you can use [Window Functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions) to create the above query:

```
from django.db.models import Window, F
from django.db.models.functions import Lead

q = TestModel.objects.annotate(
    next_val=Window(
        expression=Lead('some_integer', offset=1, default=0),
        order_by=F('id').asc()
    ), 
    difference=F('some_integer')-F('next_val')
)
```

**Note:** I have used 0 as the default value (which will be applied to the last item), to simplify the answer to prevent `FieldError` caused by subtracting Null value from Integer. you could handle returning None for last item using Django's [Case](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case) query.

Comment: Thanks! I've never took time to look at Window Functions but I guess this will happen now :)

Comment: If I just annotate `next_val` it works fine, but if I use `next_val` in another annotation like `difference` it throws error: `window functions are not allowed in GROUP BY`. What am I missing here?