# Calculate time difference with previous object on django queryset with Window annotation

Tags: django, orm, window, django-queryset

My model has a DateTimeField and a DurationField with the time elapsed from the last record inserted to the current one. I'm trying to remove the DurationField but I must be able to calculate the time elapsed "on the fly"..

This question [Difference with previous object in django queryset annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52316066/difference-with-previous-object-in-django-queryset-annotation) is quite similar to my problem. The best answer suggests using the Django Window function introduced with the version 2.0. I found that the Lead function works only using integers, but I have a DateTimeField and not an IntegerField, so I tried to convert/cast my field to a timestamp.

This is my Model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    time_elapsed = models.DurationField() # TO BE REMOVED
```

Here the actual queryset:

```
Event.objects
  .annotate(ts=Cast(Extract('date','epoch'),IntegerField()))
  .annotate(next_val=Window(
    expression=Lead('ts', offset=1,default=0),
    order_by=F('date').asc()),
    difference=F('next_val')-F('ts'))
```

It nearly works (it seems), but it takes the next object and does the difference, while I need the PREVIOUS object to subtract the current one. I can't find a solution for this.

Many thanks!

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @radoh I found the missed function (Lag), unfortunately I haven't reached my goal, yet.

Here the actual queryset:

```
qs = Event.objects
  .annotate(ts=Cast(Extract('date','epoch'),IntegerField()))
  .annotate(prev_ts=Window(expression=Lag('ts',offset=1,default=0),order_by=F('date').asc()),
    diff=F('ts')-F('prev_ts'))
```

My `diff` is now a timedelta (seconds between Event(s)), and now I would want to exclude events with a value less than 36 hours. I tried to go strait chaining filter() or exclude() to my QuerySet, but it seems that is not supported :-)

`qs.exclude(diff__lt=129600)`

> ProgrammingError: window functions are not allowed in WHERE

I found that Window functions are not allowed but I'm wondering if there is another method to do what I want. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't `Lag` help you there instead of `Lead`?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm stuck in similar situation.